# netBeans error report (details not provided)

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run the program below, netBeans reports that 'One or more projects were compiled with errors', but gives no indication as to what those errors are. However, it then goes on to say that the build is successful and the Bezier curve is drawn as required. Does anyone know a) what the thinking is behind the decision to report that there are errors but give no indication whatsoever of what the errors are? b) how to find out what the errors are?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package curve2;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
    import java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D;
        import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

public class Curve2 extends ApplicationFrame {
        // Set control points
        private int x1 = 200;
        private int y1 = 200;

        private int ctrlx = 300;
        private int ctrly = 300;

        private int x2 = 300;
        private int y2 = 500;

        // Construct frame
        public Curve2() {
              super("First Bezier Curve");
        setSize(600, 600);
            //centre();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Set points
            Point2D.Double P1 = new Point2D.Double(50, 75); // Start Point
        Point2D.Double P2 = new Point2D.Double(150, 75); // End Point
            Point2D.Double ctrl1 = new Point2D.Double(80, 25); // Control Point 1
            Point2D.Double ctrl2 = new Point2D.Double(160, 100); // Control Point 2


            CubicCurve2D.Double cubicCurve; // Cubic curve

            cubicCurve = new CubicCurve2D.Double( P1.x, P1.y, ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, P2.x, P2.y);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.draw(cubicCurve);
        }
```

Comment: If your program runs correctly, it means that it was compiled successfully. Search for the error in an another package. Netbeans is warning you that some package of your project has a problem.

Comment: Close projects till you do not get the message.

Comment: Is there any way to make netBeans only report errors on only this package? Ok- I'll try closing the projects, Godwilling.

Comment: Netbeans assumes that there is an affinity between the packages of a Project. If not, why should the packages share a common project?

Comment: Dealing with more than one Project opened is not a strength of Netbeans :( What sometimes helps is to clear the cache. Close netbeans, delete C:\Users\yourusername\.netbeans\7.1\var\cache or C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

Comment: Maybe that Window / IDE Tools / Notifications would have shown something. Same **Ctrl-.** Navigate / Next Error

Comment: try clean and build it. ^^